# Mount a host path that is a samba share into Docker container

Tags: docker, containers, mounted-volumes

I have mounted a windows share  in my host linux and I am trying to mount the host path into my Docker container. I am trying to create a container using python sdk and I able to mount the path using `privileged= True`. But I have read that using `privileged= True` is not safe. So I tried to use `cap_add =["SYS_ADMIN","DAC_READ_SEARCH"` but it is not working. Is there any other alternative to `privileged= True` ?

Comment: If the Windows share is already mounted in the host, you should be able to just bind-mount it into the container like other host content.  Have you tried this, and what results do you get?

Comment: @DavidMaze When i do docker inspect on that container..I can see the bind information. Just the files from the share are not being accessed in the container